# Windows Server Blocking Web Service?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, web-services, xml, soap

I have a program that uses a webservice that connects to a server to get software licenses.  This is blocked in Windows Server 2003, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2012 R2 by default.  However, in Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10 it works just fine by default.

On Windows Server, I have tried Disabling Firewall, Enabled/Disabled every Role, Feature, and Service.  Also tried downloading the SOAP toolbox but that didn't help.

Event Viewer shows the following, all sources are from **MSSOAP**:

```
Soap error: One of the parameters supplied is invalid.. (Client)
Soap error: Loading of the WSDL file failed. (Generic)
Soap error: XML Parser failed at linenumber 0, lineposition 0, reason is: The download of the specified resource has failed. (Generic)
```

What else could be blocking this?  This is basically a fresh install of any Windows Server without any roles and features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!  Had to **disable Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration** (IE ESC) using ServerManager.msc on Windows Server.